# How to post json data containing a file field with Guzzle?

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I'm trying to send the following data to a REST API with Guzzzle

```html
{
    "documents": {
        "id_proprietaire": 28,
        "nom_proprietaire": "rash",
        "prenom_proprietaire": "rash",
        "code_identification": "9LS9PB094MIL9CPL",
        "dossier_initial": "path_to_data"
    },
    "dossier_final": null
}
```

But I don't find how to use multipart and json requests together. Can someone help?

This is what I have done and I got a 404 bad request error field documents is required

```html
$httpClient = new Client();
$token = 'Token 7480ea9a692f98ad943e810820ced48aa09ca174';
$response =  $httpClient->post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api_memoire/signed/', [
            'headers' => [
                'Authorization' => $token,
                'Accept'        => 'application/json',
            ],
            'multipart' => [
                [
                    'name' => 'documents',
                    'contents' => json_encode(
                        [
                            'id_proprietaire' => $id_demande,
                            'nom_proprietaire' => $demande->nom,
                            'prenom_proprietaire' => $demande->prenoms,
                            'code_identification' => $code,
                            'dossier_initial' => $document,
                        ]
                    ),
                ],
                [
                    'name' => 'dossier_final',
                    'contents' => null,
                ]
            ]
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send data via Guzzle like that:

```php
$httpClient = new Client();
$token = 'Token 7480ea9a692f98ad943e810820ced48aa09ca174';
$response =  $httpClient->post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api_memoire/signed/', [
            'headers' => [
                'Authorization' => $token,
                'Accept'        => 'application/json',
            ],
            'form_params' => [
                'documents' => json_encode(
                        [
                            'id_proprietaire' => $id_demande,
                            'nom_proprietaire' => $demande->nom,
                            'prenom_proprietaire' => $demande->prenoms,
                            'code_identification' => $code,
                            'dossier_initial' => $document,
                        ]
                    ), 
                'dossier_final' => null
            ]
        ]);
```

Also, you can read more detail in [official documentation](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html?highlight=send%20post#post-form-requests)